# ¿Cómo sumar números de un string en c?

Tags: c, string

Tengo el string: `lo1lo2lo3lo4`

Quiero sumar +1 a los números del string

Entonces me quedaría asi:

```
lo2lo3lo4lo5
```

Comment: Tendrias que separar los numeros del string, luego los numeros parsearlos a int, o el tipo que sea, sumarlos y despues concatenarlo con el string

Answer (score 2):

Si los números van a ser todos de un dígito, con aritmética de punteros es casi trivial:

```
char cad[100];
strcpy(cad,"lo1lo2lo3lo4");

for( char* ptr = cad; *ptr; ++ptr )
{
  if( isdigit(*ptr) )
    *ptr = (*ptr!='9')? *ptr+1 : '0';
}
```

Si los números pudiesen ocupar más digitos habría que convertir los fragmentos correspondientes a números:

```
char cad[100];
strcpy(cad,"lo1lo99lo3lo4");
char resultado[100];

for( char* orig = cad, *dest=resultado; *dest=0 || *orig ; ++orig, ++dest )
{
  if( !isdigit(*orig) )
    *dest = *orig;
  else
  {
    int valor = 0;
    do
    {
      valor *= 10;
      valor += *orig - '0';
    } while( isdigit(*(++orig) );

    dest += sprintf(dest, "%d", valor+1) - 1;
  }
}

printf("%s",resultado);
```

EDITO: Una versión un poco más simplificada del ejemplo anterior ya que delega la lectura de los enteros:

```
char cad[100];
strcpy(cad,"lo1lo99lo3lo4");
char resultado[100];

for( char* orig = cad, *dest=resultado; *dest=0 || *orig ; ++orig, ++dest )
{
  if( !isdigit(*orig) )
    *dest = *orig;
  else
  {
    int valor;
    orig += sscanf(orig,"%d",&valor) - 1;
    dest += sprintf(dest, "%d", valor+1) - 1;
  }
}

printf("%s",resultado);
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Ojo en el segundo código, puedes desbordar el búfer al aumentar números `9` puede pasar a tener dos dígitos desde un dígito, `99` tres, `999` cuatro... por otro lado en la condición estás haciendo una asignación en lugar de una comparación en `*dest=0`.

Comment: El segundo código está pensado para pasar de 1 a 2 dígitos y así, de hecho si te fijas la cadena de entrada tiene un `99`. El problema podría ser el tamaño del buffer, que no se comprueba, pero eso ya es responsabilidad del que use el algoritmo. `*dest=0` está puesto a drede. Lo que hace es asegurarse de que la cadena `resultado` finaliza con un caracter nulo. jejeje

Comment: ¡Cierto! no es algo que se vea a simple vista... queda el bucle bastante ofuscado, pero mi aproximación tampoco es el summum de la legibilidad :)

Comment: Jajajaja. Lo he hecho simplemente por no tener que sacar el puntero `dest` fuera del bucle para finalizar la variable. Un poco ofuscado si que queda, no se puede tener todo ;)

Comment: **↑** Lindo código, ***`sprintf()`*** me ayudó a reducir el código de mi respuesta. Anteriormente usaba **`itoa()`**, que aprendí del libro ***[El lenguaje de programación C](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=OpJ_0zpF7jIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ritchie&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGo4jLmLHPAhUGlJAKHXjADHcQ6AEIMjAA#v=snippet&q=itoa&f=false)***

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función [`isalpha`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) de la cabecera `<ctype.h>` para determinar si un caracter es una letra; si no es una letra: será otra cosa (posiblemente un número).

Así pues:

```
char entrada[] = "lo1lo2lo3lo4";

for (char *letra = entrada, *fin = entrada + strlen(entrada); letra != fin; ++letra)
{
    if (!isalpha(*letra))
        ++(*letra);
}
```

El código anterior suma uno al caracter de la `entrada` cuando dicho caracter es (posiblemente) un número. Hay que tener en cuenta que este código considera `11` como dos números `1` no como el once y que no tiene en cuenta signos de puntuación ni espacios.

Puedes ver el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fnbadTmIa0AdSIdv).

---

#### Editado

La propuesta de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26203/2742) con `isdigit` es más precisa (además de controlar el caso del `9`).

Answer (score 0):

También podemos usar la función **`strtok()`**, que permite dividir una secuencia de caracteres (`char*`) en porciones, según un `char*` separador. Entonces las porciones serían los números:

> lo**2**lo**3**lo**4**lo**5** ----> 2, 3, 4, 5

El separador vendría a ser:

> lo

### Ejemplo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    // strtok()
#include <stdlib.h>    // atoi()

#define     INC         1    // El valor que se sumará.
#define     STRLENMAX   256  // La longitud máxima de las strings.
#define     SEP         "lo" // El separador.

int main()
{
    char texto[STRLENMAX] = "lo1lo25lo3lo4lo5lo6lo7lo8lo9lo10lo11lo12";
    char r[STRLENMAX] = "\0";    // Resultado.

    // Obtiene el primer token.
    char *token = strtok(texto, SEP);

    // Si hubo un token, continúa extrayendo tokens.
    while( token != NULL ) 
    {
        int suma = atoi(token) + INC;   /* atoi convierte el ascii token en int,
                                           y luego se suma INC */
        char snum[10];
        sprintf(snum, "%i", suma);      // Convierte el int suma en una char*
        strcat(r, SEP);                 // Concatena el separador SEP con 
        strcat(r, snum);                //  el resultado de la suma.

        token = strtok(NULL, SEP);      // Siguiente token.
    }

    printf("r = %s\n", r);    // Muestra el resultado.

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Otro ejemplo, pero esta vez para los casos de delimitadores variables:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    // strspn(), strcspn(), strncpy(), strcat(), strncat(), memset()
#include <stdlib.h>    // atoi()

#define     INC         1    // El valor que se sumará.
#define     STRLENMAX   256  // La longitud máxima de las strings.
#define     NUMBERS     "0123456789"

int main()
{
    char texto[STRLENMAX] = "lo1lo25lo3lo4loto500loteria6lo7lo8lo9lo10lo11lo12";
    char* p = texto;            // Apunta las posiciones de la variable texto.
    char r[STRLENMAX] = "\0";   // Resultado.
    char sn[10];                // Salva el número que será convertido en int.

    int b = 1;  // Bandera para saber si se está buscando texto (b = 0) o números (b = 1).

    do
    {
        // Cuenta los char hasta encontrar un dígito, cuando b = 0
        // o cuenta los char hasta encontrar un char que no es dígito, cuando b = 1
        size_t t = b ? strspn(p, NUMBERS) : strcspn(p, NUMBERS);

        if (b && t)     // Con b se comprueba si se están buscando dígitos, y
        {               // con t si se ha encontrado al menos uno.
            memset(sn, '\0', sizeof(sn));   // Limpia el vector sn.
            strncpy(sn, p, t);              // Copia en sn los chars que van
                                            // desde texto[p] hasta texto[p + t - 1]
            int suma = atoi(sn) + INC;
            sprintf(sn, "%i", suma);
            strcat(r, sn);                  // Realiza la concatenación r = r + sn
        }
        else if (!b)                        // Comprueba si no se están buscando dígitos.
            strncat(r, p, t);               // Concatena en r, r y los chars que van
                                            // desde texto[p] hasta texto[p + t - 1]
        b = !b;                             // Actualiza la bandera.
        p += sizeof(char) * t;              // p son los caracteres que ya se han analizado

    }while(*p);                             // Mientras haya char en texto[].

    printf("r = '%s' \n", r);

    return 0;
}
```